# How can we encourage "userxxxxx" accounts to fix their usernames?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I've noticed there's a *lot* more accounts with names like "user1234" around here, than I'm used to seeing at other sites.  Is there any way we can encourage these people to create unique, identifying usernames?  Granted the usernames are technically unique, and are often accompanied by a unique graphic, these anonymous-ish accounts are still starting to blur together a bit, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Users are prompted to edit their user page at the time of account creation, if they register -- this is done via topbar notification.

[image: welcome to it security! visit your user page to set your name and email]

Comment: Stupid question:  Absent a built-in PM system, (which I still think would be nice, but has probably been shot down before) how do mods contact (the rare) abusers of the system if they *don't* set an e-mail?

Comment: @iszi I think characterizing this as "abuse" is not really correct

Answer (score 0):

@Iszi - with the subject matter we have on this site, some folks could require a little anonymity in order to ask questions that might otherwise leak sensitive information about the environment they work in. I agree with you that it would be nice to know everyone's name and be able to distinguish between them, but I think we would lose some potentially useful members of the community if people were forced to pick a more unique identifier (I know, bad English :-)

Admittedly - all the names are actually unique, so having people pick a nickname would not really change security, but perception is key.

Comment: Agreed, if we support anonymous postings, we allow people to name themselves user1701 or whatever they want: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/37/should-we-support-anonymous-postings